# How to shallow clone and deep clone in java?

Tags: java, cloning

I have three classes inside a package `pack1`. The three classes are `classA`  `classB` and `classC`.

`classA`

```
public class Address {
    public String town = null;
    public String street = null;
    public int postCode = 0;
    public int houseNumber = 0;
}
```

`classB`

```
public class Course {
    public String number;
    public String name;

    public Course(){
        number = null;
        name = null;
    }
```

`classC`

```
public class Student {
    public Date dob;
    public Course course = new Course();
    public Address address = new Address();


    public Student(){
        dob = null;
        course.name = null;
        course.number = null;
        address.town = null;
        address.street = null;
        address.postCode = 0;
        address.houseNumber = 0;
        course.name = null;
        course.number = null;

    }
```

I'm wanting to know how I deep clone address and dob and the shallow clone course? I don't know how to do the combos of cloning yet

Answer (score 2):

ShallowCopy:
The shallow copy of an object will have exact copy of all the fields of original object. If original object has any references to other objects as fields, then only references of those objects are copied into clone object, copy of those objects are not created.

Deep Copy:
Deep copy of an object will have exact copy of all the fields of original object just like shallow copy. But in additional, if original object has any references to other objects as fields, then copy of those objects are also created by calling clone() method on them

As the course entity does not have any object refrences therefore its cloning down using defalut clone method.
Student Entity as the refrences to Date , Course  , Address we need to override clone method.
Below is the sample code:-

```
public static class Address implements Cloneable{
    public String town = null;
    public String street = null;
    public int postCode = 0;
    public int houseNumber = 0;

    public Address(String town , String street ,int postCode , int houseNumber){
        this.town = town;
        this.street = street;
        this.postCode = postCode;
        this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
    }
    public Address(){
    }

    //Default version of clone() method. It creates shallow copy of an object.

    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        return super.clone();
    }
}

public static class Course implements Cloneable{
    public String number;
    public String name;

    public Course(){
        number = null;
        name = null;
    }

    public Course(String number , String name){
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
    }

  //Default version of clone() method. It creates shallow copy of an object.

    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        return super.clone();
    }

} 

 public static class Student implements Cloneable{
        public Date dob;
        public Course course = new Course();
        public Address address = new Address();



        public Student(){
            dob = null;
            course.name = null;
            course.number = null;
            address.town = null;
            address.street = null;
            address.postCode = 0;
            address.houseNumber = 0;

        }

        public Student(Date dob , Course course , Address address){
            this.dob = dob;
            this.course = course;
            this.address = address;
        }

        protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
        {
            Student student = (Student) super.clone();

            student.course = (Course) course.clone();
            student.address = (Address) address.clone();
            student.dob = (Date) dob.clone();

            return student;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [sugar-cubes-cloner](https://github.com/sugar-cubes/sugar-cubes-cloner) library. It is very fast and well documented. It also allows the developer to configure the cloning process very flexible on the level of classes, fields and objects.

In your case:

```java
Cloner cloner = Cloners.builder()
  .shallow(Course.class)
  .build();
Student clone = cloner.clone(student);
```

Answer (score 0):

In **ShallowCopy** only reference value is copied, so if you make any changes to it will directly affect the original copy of that object. 
But in **DeepCopy** you have to create a new instance of that object and initialize it with the values of the original object and return the newly initialized object.

You have to do this inside the clone method. So that when clone is called deepcopy is performed.

Answer (score -1):

To do a shallow copy, you just set one variable equal to another.  A shallow copy means that the original and the copy are really the same object.  If you have:

```
course2 = course1;
course2.name = "math";
```

then `course1`'s name will also change to "math", because course1 and course2 are the same object.

To do a deep clone, you must copy everything in the object, instead of the object itself.

```
course2 = new Course();
course2.name = course1.name;
//... 
course2.name = "math";
```

In this case, course1's name will not change, because `course2` itself was made as a new object, and was not set to `course1`.

Comment: the assignment `course2 = course1` is no shallow copy, it's just reference. shallow or deep refers to the way that the object properties of a copied object are managed